# A simple integration problem.

Tags: calculus

> I must find the following:
>   $$\int (x^2 + 1)^{50}\,dx$$

1. Would rewriting it as $50\ln(x^2+1)$ and then integrating be wrong?
2. Using regular the substitution $u= x^2+1$, I get the answer to be $$\dfrac{x(x^2+1)^{51}}{51}+C$$

Wolfram gives me an answer that is in expanded form (half a page) plus sometimes it uses integration techniques that are beyond my basic level.

Any feedback would be appreciated... especially as to why (1) wouldn't work.
Thanks

Comment: Why do you think that those two functions are the same?

Comment: 1. Surely wrong since $f(x)\ne \ln f(x)$. 2. Wrong too.

Comment: your primitive function is wrong

Comment: (1) does not work... Just because the identity $$\ln\int f(x)\,dx=\int\ln f(x)\,dx$$ is **wrong**. (If I understood correctly what you wanted)

Comment: or you can expand $(x^2+1)^{50}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Would rewriting it as $50\ln(x^2+1)$ then integrating be wrong?

Yes, because $$\int (x^2 + 1)^{50} dx=\int e^{50\ln(x^2 + 1)} dx\ne \int 50\ln(x^2 + 1) dx$$

> Using regular the substitution $u=x^2+1$, I get the answer to be $\frac{x(x^2+1)^{51}}{51}+C$

Let $u=x^2+1,\quad x=\sqrt{u-1},\quad dx=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{u-1}}\,du$. Then
$$\int (x^2 + 1)^{50} dx=\int \frac{u^{50}}{2\sqrt{u-1}}\,du$$

Comment: Thank You for your feedback

Answer (score 2):

Consider the binomial expansion

$$(x^2+1)^{50}=\sum_{k=0}^{50}\binom{50}{k}x^{2k}$$

Because the integral is linear, one has

$$\int(x^2+1)^{50}dx=\int \left( \sum_{k=0}^{50}\binom{50}{k}x^{2k} \right )dx=\sum_{k=0}^{50}\binom{50}{k}\int x^{2k}dx=\sum_{k=0}^{50}\binom{50}{k}\frac{x^{2k+1}}{2k+1}$$

$1$ is wrong because

$$\int f(x)dx\ne\int \log(f(x))dx$$

in general. Consider the obvious counterexample

$$\int 1 dx=x+C\neq \int \log(1)dx=0$$

There does not exist a $C$ such that the two expressions are the same for every $x$, i.e. they do not differ by a constant.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more why that manipulation with the sum is valid?

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD Well, simply by linearity. $\int(f(x)+g(x))dx= \int f(x)dx+\int g(x)dx$. Since the sum is finite, we can apply the same reasoning to a sum with multiple (50) expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: try to do [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem) first
$$
(x^2+1)^{50}=\sum_{k=0}^{50}{50 \choose k}x^{2k}.
$$
That's perhaps what Wolfram is saying.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use the binomial theorem, then you can integrate it easily because it's a polynomial, even though it has degree 100...

Answer (score 0):

By parts,

$$I_n=\int(x^2+1)^ndx=x(x^2+1)^n-2n\int x^2(x^2+1)^{n-1}dx\\=x(x^2+1)^n-2n\int (x^2+1)^ndx+2n\int(x^2+1)^{n-1}dx.$$

Hence

$$I_n=\frac{x(x^2+1)^n}{2n+1}+\frac{2n}{2n+1}I_{n-1},$$

and

$$I_0=x.$$